# How do you render EditFrame programmatically in C#?

Tags: experience-editor, sitecore-react

I am working on an inherited project that was built with minimal support for editing with the Experience Editor (`Sitecore` 8.2.4). In particular, I need to retrofit `EditFrames` [(documentation link)](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/developing/developing_with_sitecore/using_editframes).

For some background, the project uses the [Sitecore.React](https://github.com/GuitarRich/sitecore.react) project as its view engine (razor is replaced by React JS), so existing razor helpers for `EditFrame` rendering were not available.

How can I programmatically supply/build `EditFrames` within the MVC C# code?

Answer (score 8):

I was able to supply the view layer with `EditFrame` HTML by adding the opening and closing HTML markup into my MVC Model.

## HTMLHelper

Step 1: Obtain access to HtmlHelper using your current context Controller and a "Fake View".

```
public static HtmlHelper GetHtmlHelper(this Controller controller)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(sb, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, new FakeView(), controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, htw);
    return new HtmlHelper(viewContext, new ViewPage());
}
```

An example of using fake view can be found [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/how-to-render-an-asp-net-mvc-view-as-a-string).

## EditFrame Rendering

Step 2: Use the EditFrameRendering class (similar to that in [Habitat](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Foundation/SitecoreExtensions/code/Controls/EditFrameRendering.cs)) to obtain the opening and closing HTML markup.

```
public void SetEditDatasourceEditFrame(IComponentModelBase model, Controller controller)
{
    var htmlHelper = controller.GetHtmlHelper();
    EditFrameRendering editFrame = new EditFrameRendering(htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer, model.DataSourcePath, _editFrameLocation, "Edit Component", string.Empty, string.Empty, null);
    model.EditDatasourceStart = editFrame.EditFrameStart();
    model.EditDatasourceEnd = editFrame.EditFrameEnd();
}
```

## EditFrameRendering.cs

Note the modification to [EditFrameRendering.cs](https://github.com/TomTyack/Sitecore-Programmatic-Editframes/blob/master/src/Foundation/Editing/code/ExperienceEditor/EditFrameRendering.cs) from the Habitat project to support the code above.

```
public string EditFrameStart()
{
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    // Put HtmlTextWriter in using block because it needs to call Dispose.
    using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        this._editFrame.RenderFirstPart(writer);
    }
    // Return the result.
    return stringWriter.ToString();
}

public string EditFrameEnd()
{
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    // Put HtmlTextWriter in using block because it needs to call Dispose.
    using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        this._editFrame.RenderLastPart(writer);
    }
    // Return the result.
    return stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

## View Layer

In your view layer access the model, writing out the start and end HTML. Adding any content to go within the edit frame between the tags.

Example React View:

```
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');

...

editFrameMarkup() {
    const content = (<div>My Edit Frame</div>);
    return (<li><div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup(this.props.data.EditDatasourceStart, content, this.props.data.EditDatasourceEnd)} /></li>);
},

createMarkup(open, content, close) {
    const htmlString = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(content);
    const wrapper = open + htmlString + close;
    return { __html: wrapper };
}
```

The above markup was taken from a reusable react component used across all renderings. The model was passed to this react component as a property called data.

The Github example is [available here.](https://github.com/TomTyack/Sitecore-Programmatic-Editframes)